# Why the flag is true all the time even if setting it to false?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Rotate : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject[] objectsToRotate;
    public float duration = 5f;
    public static bool desiredAngle = false;

    private Vector3 lastFwd;
    private bool startRot = true;

    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        if (startRot == true)
        {
            startRot = false;
            StartCoroutine(StartRotationOfObjects());
        }
    }

    private IEnumerator StartRotationOfObjects()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
        {
            // Random wait period before rotation starts
            if (i == 0)
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
            }
            else
            {
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
            }

            StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
        }

        startRot = true;
    }

    private IEnumerator Rotates(Transform objectToRotate, float duration)
    {
        Quaternion startRot = objectToRotate.rotation;
        float t = 0.0f;
        lastFwd = objectToRotate.transform.forward;

        while (t < duration)
        {
            t += Time.deltaTime;

            objectToRotate.rotation = startRot * Quaternion.AngleAxis(t / duration * 360f, Vector3.up);

            var curFwd = objectToRotate.transform.forward;
            // measure the angle rotated since last frame:
            var ang = Vector3.Angle(curFwd, lastFwd);

            if (myApproximation(ang, 179f, 1f) == true)
            {
                desiredAngle = true;
            }

            yield return null;
        }
        objectToRotate.rotation = startRot;

        desiredAngle = false;
    }

    private bool myApproximation(float a, float b, float tolerance)
    {
        return (Mathf.Abs(a - b) < tolerance);
    }
}
```

I want to disable the OnMouseDown code so I will not be able to execute the Coroutine nonstop times. And after all the objects finished rotating then to enable the OnMouseDown again. I'm using the startRot flag for that but still it's true all the time and I can keep start the coroutine inside the OnMouseDown nonstop.

Comment: you want to store the flag in the different event in the game, for which you can use PlayerPrefs. This is common practice for storing player/game data. try googling it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a simplified version of your code.

```
private void OnMouseDown()
{
    if (startRot == true)
    {
        startRot = false;
        StartCoroutine(StartRotationOfObjects());
    }
}

private IEnumerator StartRotationOfObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
        }
        StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
    }

    startRot = true;
}

private IEnumerator Rotates(Transform objectToRotate, float duration)
{
    while (condition)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

First, you have the OnMouseDown checking if true and it is on first run so it enters, sets it to false and start the coroutine.

Moving on with the loop. The first if check is useless since wait for 0 seconds. But it actually impacts the experience. So on first run, it enters the statement and basically does not wait. It then moves on to start the Rotates coroutine.

Entering the coroutine, it will reach a yield statement, place the coroutine in a list of coroutines to run and return. Back in the loop, it runs again, this time it will wait for  to 2 seconds and run the next coroutine and so on until last one of the objectsToRotate collection.

Loop is done, startRot is set back to true. This means, even though, your coroutines may not be done, you can trigger new ones.

Your solution, either you want to wait for one rotation to be done before starting a new one with:

```
        if (i == 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
        }
        yield StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration));
```

or you need to keep track of any coroutine running:

```
private int index = 0;
private IEnumerator StartRotationOfObjects()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < objectsToRotate.Length; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(0);
        }
        else
        {
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(Random.Range(0, 2f));
        }
        StartCoroutine(Rotates(objectsToRotate[i].transform, duration);
    }
    while(index > 0){ yield return null; }
    startRot = true;
}

private IEnumerator Rotates(Transform objectToRotate, float duration)
{
    index++;
    while (condition)
    {
        yield return null;
    }
    index--;
}
```

Now anytime you start a coroutine, index is increased, at the end of the coroutine, it is decreased, in the main coroutine, you yield until index is back to 0.

Comment: I'ld guess that even having `WaitForSeconds` with `0` might still yield at least once -> waits for one frame